# c# Async Socket.BeginSendFile only sends two files async

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

I am puzzled at why my **Socket.BeginSendFile** only sends two files async at a time.  I have tested on different computer with the same results.

***Socket.BeginSend*** seems to send all three at once as expected.

I tested connecting three clients to the server. Which works great, all three connect async as expected.  Each client (Test100.exe, Test200.exe, Test300.exe in picture) will request a file from either a folder named 100, 200 or 300 from the server depending on the which client connected.

The problem is that **Socket.BeginSendFile** is only sending max two files at a time onto the stream.  As soon as one of the 2 previously called **Socket.BeginSendFile** have finished. See below;
[image]

**As soon as one of the first two clients sending finishes the send, the third begins receiving.**

[image]

Putting some breakpoints into the code, I can tell that all three Socket.BeginSendFile(...) are being called async.

```
    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        string dateFolder =  data.Replace("<EOF>", "");

        string longFileName = "C:\\"+dateFolder+"\\poopoo.txt";
        string shortFileName = "poopoo.txt";

        // ==== for beginSend
        //byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
        // ==== for beginSend


        byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
        byte[] fileInfo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("C:\\Users\\Trim\\Desktop");
        byte[] fileInfoLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileInfo.Length); // we know these are ints (4bytes)

        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileInfoLen.Length + fileInfo.Length];// + fileData.Length + eofByte.Length
        // ==== for beginSend
        //byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileInfoLen.Length + fileInfo.Length + fileData.Length];
        // ==== for beginSend

        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length); // we know these are int (4bytes);

        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4); // room for error file name 4bytes?
        fileInfoLen.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
        fileInfo.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileInfoLen.Length);

        // ==== for beginSend
        //fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileInfoLen.Length + fileInfo.Length);
        // ==== for beginSend
        // *** Break point shows all three being called async
        handler.BeginSendFile(longFileName, clientData, null, 0, new AsyncCallback(AsynchronousFileSendCallback), handler);



       // handler.BeginSend(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);


    }
```

The third Socket.BeginSendFile(...) doesnt actually begin to send the file until one of the first two AsynchronousFileSendCallback methods

```
    private static void AsynchronousFileSendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        client.EndSendFile(ar); // **Third** client doesn't actually start receiving his data until EndSendFile is called atleast once.

        Console.WriteLine("Send file to client.");
       // sendDone.Set();
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }
```

As I said earlier, if I use **Socket.BeginSend** the issue goes away.  Although I need to be able to use **Socket.BeginSendFile** because it chunks the file on a separate thread and particularly this line of code `byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);` used with my **Socket.BeginSend** structure is unacceptable for large files :(

Thank you all very much for your time!

Comment: Not sure if this applies to socket-level stuff, but the `ServicePointManager`'s default connection limit is 2 per server. Perhaps that's getting in the way? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that BeginSendFile uses the Windows API function TransmitFile to do its job. And this API is limited to 2 concurrent transfers on *client* versions of Windows.

> Workstation and client versions of Windows optimize the TransmitFile function for minimum memory and resource utilization by limiting the number of concurrent TransmitFile operations allowed on the system to a maximum of two. On Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, and Windows NT Workstation 3.51 and later only two outstanding TransmitFile requests are handled simultaneously; the third request will wait until one of the previous requests is completed.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head there good sir, thank you so much :)